# How do you Qualify a Type Name in a Constructor for an Object which has a Member of the Same Name?

Tags: c++, struct, types, syntax

Suppose I have the following 2 structs.

```
struct ErrorCodes
{
    const unsigned long UsbErrorCode
    const DWORD DriverErrorCode;

    ErrorCodes(const unsigned long usbErrorCode, const DWORD driverErrorCode)
        : UsbErrorCode(usbErrorCode),
        WinDriverErrorCode(winDriverErrorCode)
    {
    }
}

struct Response
{
    const char* Message;
    const ErrorCodes ErrorCodes;

    Response(const char* message, const ErrorCodes errorCodes)
        : Message(message),
        ErrorCodes(errorCodes)
    {
    }
}
```

How do I qualify `const ErrorCodes` in the constructor of `Response` so that the compiler knows I'm referring to the type `ErrorCodes` and not the member `ErrorCodes`?  I don't want to change names as this needs to map-up to a C# struct for interop.

The compiler error I currently get is: `member "Response::ErrorCodes" is not a type name`.

Comment: Well, just rename it. Why are you using the same name for both the type and the variable to begin with???

Comment: @4xy Thanks - the global namespace was just what I was looking for - I was trying to use the C# equivalent of `global::` to no avail!

Comment: @goodvibration It needs to map-up to a C# struct for interop - the C# struct uses properties instead of fields which, by convention, are pascal case.  The names are the same because there wasn't a more logical and specific name for the `UsbErrorCodes` of `Response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `::` to `ErrorCodes` type if it's in global namespace or `ns::` if it's in namespace `ns` or whatever name you would like. Like `::ErrorCodes`. And as mentioned by @goodvibration in comment it's better avoid such name collisions.

```
const ::ErrorCodes ErrorCodes;
```

`::` is the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the type. Or move it into a separate namespace.

```
namespace ns {
struct ErrorCodes
{
    const unsigned long UsbErrorCode;
    const int DriverErrorCode;

    ErrorCodes(const unsigned long usbErrorCode, const int driverErrorCode)
        : UsbErrorCode(usbErrorCode),
        DriverErrorCode(driverErrorCode)
    {
    }
};
}

struct Response
{
    const char* Message;
    const ns::ErrorCodes ErrorCodes;

    Response(const char* message, const ns::ErrorCodes errorCodes)
        : Message(message),
        ErrorCodes(errorCodes)
    {
    }
};
```